# Memory leaking in windows service

Tags: powershell, memory-leaks, windows-services, windows-server-2012-r2

I had made a windows service following this article - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt703436.aspx. All works fine and I felt like I’m a real programmer). But I have a problem - this service consumes too much memory. In fact, for about 6 hours service consumed 3 Gb memory and I think it’s not very good. Maybe anyone faced with this problem and resolve it?
Maybe someone could help me?
I put my code here - http://paste.ubuntu.com/24169803/.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's going to be quite hard to help without being able to see the code.

Comment: Edited first message.

Comment: Over 1,000 lines of code?? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
I guess as a generic answer: how often are you creating `New-Object`s and not clearing them up?

Comment: I'll check it, thanks for this hint.

Comment: I added the Remove-Item commandlet in every functions where are the New-Object. But it's not helped.

Comment: And also I found this code in finally block:

`if ($sw) {
      
$sw.Dispose() # Release resources
      
$sw = $null   # Force the PowerShell garbage collector to delete the .net object
    
}`

Answer (score 0):

I've read the article you used for creating a service. Can't tell for sure without seeing your code but you are probably missing garbage cleaners.

```
[System.GC]::Collect()
```

Comment: I tried to use garbage collecting, but there was no any effect.